What is the amortized time complexity of Haskell's `!?` operator?
The documentation says:

List index (subscript) operator, starting from 0. Returns Nothing if the index is out of bounds
This is the total variant of the partial !! operator.
WARNING: This function takes linear time in the index.

However a timing suggests otherwise, perhaps because of the way GHC only computes expressions once per evaluation of the outer context?
ghci> length $ map ([0..10^8-1] !?) . map (`mod` (10^8 - 1)) $ [0..1 * 10^8 - 1]
100000000
(1.16 secs, 24,800,308,224 bytes)
ghci> length $ map ([0..10^8-1] !?) . map (`mod` (10^8 - 1)) $ [0..4 * 10^8 - 1]
400000000
(4.55 secs, 99,200,308,200 bytes)

Does anyone know of an authoritative reference to figure this out?

It does not compute !? at all: you ask for the length of the list, therefore it does not need to determine the items in the list itself.

"Does anyone know of an authoritative reference to figure this out?" → Yes, the documentation you quoted.

Also, the data you post here is compatible with (!?) being linear time. Your second invocation has merely done the same thing as the first invocation four times -- so it will take about four times as long, no matter what the asymptotics of (!?) are.

Okay, so my timing code does not do what I thought it did. In general if I want to force evaluation of every subexpression of some expression, how can I do that, to get accurate profiling information?

Also, what is the true amortized time complexity of (!?). The documentation does not answer this question because it does not specify whether what they're giving is amortized or not.

Amortized over what? This doesn't make any sense for !?

Fix the list you're indexing into. If you access m !? 0 many many times, is the time complexity amortized constant because of the way the expression should only be evaluated once?

No, that would require caching, that's also not what is commonly understood by amortized complexity.

Fair, perhaps my use of terminology was wrong. But are you very sure about your no? Got a source? I think it's more subtle than you seem to think. See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57000994/ghc-are-there-consistent-rules-for-memoization-for-calls-with-fixed-values

Accessing m !? 0 is constant-time, even without amortization, because 0 is constant. Invoking the function (m !?) on an unknown value n many times takes time linear in n each time, because the implementation of (!?) demands both its arguments before it begins reducing. Accessing m !? n many times for some unknown value n take time linear in n the first time and constant time thereafter. N.B. the difference between the last two scenarios is manual, not automatic: you must use let or where to name the value produced by m !? n to get the benefits of reuse.


However a timing suggests otherwise.

It does not compute !? at all: you ask for the length of the list, therefore it does not need to determine the items in the list itself. Indeed, length is essentially determined as:
length :: [a] -> Int
length [] = 0
length (_:xs) = 1 + length xs

It does not have to evaluate the items of the list. If you thus would have something like:
length [undefined, undefined]

it will still return 2, and for:
length [slow_function, slow_function]

it will never even trigger the slow_functions.
Lists in Haskell are implemented like Lisp lists [wiki] which are quite similar to linked lists in for example Java, except that these are not mutable. It thus requires to walk through n nodes to reach the n-th node, and thus scales linear. The second time you walk through the same list indeed will likely be (a bit) faster than the first time, due to caching, but still require n hops, but it will take the machine often a bit less time to do one hop.
Lists are therefore not suited for random access [wiki] operations: typically lists are used to enumerate over it. If you need random access, you typically use an Array [Hackage], or some other data structure for this.

Thank you for explaining why my test was bad, but this does not answer the question. Can you come up with a corrected profiling script that will show us what the amortized time complexity is?

@lanf: use deepseq https://hackage.haskell.org/package/deepseq-1.5.0.0/docs/Control-DeepSeq.html#v:deepseq as explained in the answer, we each time enumerate over the entire list, so the amortized cost remains linear.

Apologies, I misunderstood the bit about the hops. Thanks that looks like exactly what I was looking for :)
